# Request.Form POSTED variable empty

Tags: c#, .net, ajax

I have verified by using the browser debugger / network monitor that I am sending in a variable in an AJAX call called "search" and in the monitor it shows in the header as "search=test".  I am trying to access this variable in the code behind but can't seem to find it?  Here is my code for front and back-end, am I missing something?

Code Behind :

```
public class AJAXSearchLog : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        string searchTerm = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["search"]);
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm)){
           AspDotNetStorefrontCore.DB.ExecuteSQL("insert into TribSearch(SearchTerm,CustomerID,LocaleSetting) values(" + DB.SQuote(CommonLogic.Ellipses(searchTerm, 97, true)) + "," + '0' + "," + DB.SQuote("en-us") + ")");
        }
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.Write(searchTerm);
        context.Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Front-End

```
  window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
        if ($("#searchBox_text").val().length >= 2) {
        var _search = $("#searchBox_text").val();
            var url = "/AJAXSearchLog.ashx";
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: {'search': _search},
                contentType: 'application/json;',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('error');
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: This is unlikely to be the reason, but it doesn't look right to query HttpContext.Current.Request.Form rather than context.Request.Form

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in ŷour handler code, does it get picked up when debugging? If not, make sure you've registered the handler properly in your web.config file.

Comment: @NeilMoss I'm able to successfully hit the break point in the code, but it just reads the string that I've assigned as `Request.Form["search"]` as null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found that the data wasn't getting passed through when the `contentType` was set to 'application/json'.  Also, to read the POST variable, `Request.Params[]` was needed.  Here are the 2 lines of code that I changed :

in the front-end -
`contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',`

in the back-end -
`string searchTerm = Convert.ToString(context.Request.Params["search"]);`

Comment: Thanks! The contentType you listed was what I was missing. I found this also works using `context.Request.Form["search"]`.