# Delete image from folder using AJAX C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to delete an image from a folder by using AJAX and C#. I have created a handler called Delete.ashx to delete the image. I also have an AJAX function to get the image path and pass the path to the handler

In AJAX I have a variable that gets the path which is stored in a textbox (just for now). I make an attempt to pass that path to my handler, however the problem is that the variable in the handler which I am trying to pass the data path to is always empty.

Here is my code:

Handler

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string sFileName = context.Request["sFileName"]; //this variable is always empty
    if (File.Exists(context.Server.MapPath("~/images/" + sFileName)))
    {
        File.Delete(context.Server.MapPath("~/images/" + sFileName));
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Image deleted Successfully!");
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Image Failed to Delete!");
    }
}
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnDelete").click(function () {
        removeFile();
        return false;
    });

    function removeFile() {
        var FileName = $("#txtPath").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Delete.ashx',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 'sFileName': FileName},
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });

    }

});
```

Please advise how I can pass data from AJAX to the handler so that the variable is not empty. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request.Form POSTED variable empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905741/request-form-posted-variable-empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Mennan I have done the following and is working:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string sFileName = context.Request["sFileName"];
        if (File.Exists(context.Server.MapPath("~/images/" + sFileName)))
        {
            File.Delete(context.Server.MapPath("~/images/" + sFileName));
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("Image deleted Successfully!");
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("Image Failed to Delete!");
        }
    }


function removeFile() {
    var FileName = $("#txtPath").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Delete.ashx?sFileName=' + FileName,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'sFileName': FileName},
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

try to get context from current HttpContext:

## 1

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var context_= System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
    string sFileName = context_.Request["sFileName"];
    if (File.Exists(context_.Server.MapPath("~/images/" + sFileName)))
    {
        File.Delete(context_.Server.MapPath("~/images/" + sFileName));
        context_.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context_.Response.Write("Image deleted Successfully!");
    }
    else
    {
        context_.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context_.Response.Write("Image Failed to Delete!");
    }
}
```

## 2

Or send data with querystring from ajax

```
 modify ajax:
 url: 'Delete.ashx?sFileName=blabla',

 server side:
 var sFileName= Request.Form["sFileName"];
```

Comment: with this, it doesn't reach my handler

Comment: try #2, modified

Comment: Sorry I am talking about #2, With the first suggestion, it reaches the handler but still returns a null

Comment: did u try this ? url: 'Delete.ashx?sFileName=blabla'

Comment: Busy trying this. On the server side I get: The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Ok so I only needed to put this:  url: 'Delete.ashx?sFileName=blabla',

However now it returns blabla and I want to pass the path name from the textbox. How can I do this?

Comment: url: 'Delete.ashx?sFileName=' + $("#txtPath").val(),

Comment: Thanks I also did similar to this. This what I did url: 'Delete.ashx?sFileName=' + FileName,